# Bash: Split each letter of a string

Tags: string, bash, split

How do I split each letter of a string and evaluate it in a case statement?  I want to be able to enter a reply such as "TEST TEST" and it return: -....-SP-....-

It's basically a morse code translator.  Here's what I have.  I think the problem is in the printf statement but I can't figure it out.  It's not parsing the individual letters correctly.  It's only returning the E value.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "What would you like to translate?"

for ((i=0; i<${#REPLY};i++))
  do
case $REPLY in
*E*)
  echo "." ;;
*S*)
  echo "..." ;;
*T*)
  echo "-" ;;
*' '*)
  echo "SP" ;;
esac
   printf "code: %s" "{$REPLY:i:1}]}" {$REPLY:i:1}
done
```

Comment: `${REPLY:i:1}`, not `{$REPLY:i:1}` in your `printf`s, btw.

Comment: Also, if you're iterating one character at a time, you don't need to test `*E*)`, but just can test `E)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
case $REPLY in
```

to

```
case ${REPLY:i:1} in
```

...to extract individual characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
$ str=foobar; for ((i=0; i<${#str}; i++)); do echo ${str:$i:1}; done
f
o
o
a        
r
```

or

```
$ fold -w1 <<< foobar
f
o
o
a        
r
```